# Cannot find control with path angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on the hotel project with Angular. My reservation screen opens as modal. Input is generated automatically according to the number of adults and children. But when I write to input, I get the error Cannot find control with path: 'adultArray' or Cannot find control with path: 'childArray'. How can I fix?

.html

```
<div class="container mt-4">
    <div class="row">
        <ng-container formArrayName="adultArray">
                <div *ngFor="let adult of rezForm.controls.adultArray?.value; let i = index" class="col-md-6 ">
                    <ng-container [formGroupName]="adult">
                        <div class="form-group input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text">Yetişkin</span>
                            </div>
                            <input class="form-control" formControlName="nameSurname" placeholder="Adı Soyadı" type="text" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend ">
                                <span class="input-group-text">Yetişkin</span>
                            </div>
                            <input class="form-control" formControlName="birthday" placeholder="Doğum Tarihi" type="text" />
                        </div>
                    </ng-container>
                </div>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container mt-4">
    <div class="row">
        <ng-container formArrayName="childArray">
            <div *ngFor="let chd of rezForm.controls.childArray?.value; let i = index" class="col-md-6">
                <ng-container [formGroupName]="chd">
                    <div class="form-group input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">Çocuk</span>
                        </div>
                        <input class="form-control" formControlName="nameSurname" placeholder="Adı Soyadı" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">Çocuk</span>
                        </div>
                        <input class="form-control" formControlName="birthday" placeholder="Doğum Tarihi" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </ng-container>
            </div>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
```

.ts

```
 rezForm: FormGroup;
rezervasyon: Rezervasyon;

constructor(
    private hotelservice: HotelService,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<RezervasyonComponent>
) { }



createRezervasyon() {
    this.rezForm = this.fb.group({
        adultArray: this.fb.array([]),
        childArray: this.fb.array([]),
        price: ["", Validators.required],
        hotelName: ["", Validators.required],
        roomName: ["", Validators.required],
        checkInDate: ["", Validators.required],
        payDate: ["", Validators.required],
        duration: ["", Validators.required]
    });
}

ngOnInit() {

    this.createRezervasyon();

    of(this.hotel).subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log(data);

            var adultCount = data.numberOfAd;
            let adultArray = this.rezForm.controls.adultArray as FormArray;
            let adult: any = {
                "nameSurname": "",
                "birthday": ""
            };

            for (let i = 0; i < adultCount; i++) {
                adultArray.push(this.fb.group(adult));
            }

            var childCount = data.numberOfChd;
            let childArray = this.rezForm.controls.childArray as FormArray;
            let child: any = {
                "nameSurname": "",
                "birthday": ""
            };

            for (let i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                childArray.push(this.fb.group(child));
            }

            this.rezForm.patchValue({
                hotelName: data.hotelName,
                price: data.price,
                roomName: data.roomName,
                checkInDate: data.checkInDate,
                payDate: data.payDate,
                duration: data.duration,
            });
        },
        err => {
            console.error("Hata oluştu: ", err);
        }
    );
```

Comment: A couple of ideas:

1. In your html, wrap everything in a `<form [formGroup]="rezForm ">`. From the [Angular docs on FormArrayName](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArrayName).

2. When trying to access `adultArray` and `childArray`, try using `this.rezForm.get("adultArray")` instead.

Answer (score 3):

1.- use a *ngIf to avoid initial errors

```
<form *ngIf="rezForm" [formGroup"]="rezForm>
   ...
</form>
```

2.- iterate over rezForm.get('childArray').controls, NOT over "value" (*)

```
<div *ngFor="let chd of rezForm.get('childArray').controls; let i = index">
```

else you will have problems with focus

(*) in production you need make a getter to return an FormArray

```
get childArray()
{
    return this.rezForm.get('childArray') as FormArray
}

    <div *ngFor="let chd of childArray.controls; let i = index">
```

**Updated**, but the problem is that you has write

```
<ng-container [formGroupName]="adult">
```

must be

```
<ng-container [formGroupName]="i"> //<--use "i", the let i=index
//or
<ng-container [formGroup]="adult"> //<--use "formGroup" the *ngFor="let adult of ..
```

Another problem I see is (but it's mine preference, your code work) when you write in code

```
let adultArray = this.rezForm.controls.adultArray as FormArray;
// I prefer
const adultArray = this.rezForm.get("adultArray") as FormArray;
```

See a [stackblitz with your code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tcmwpd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I did but the problem was not solved. The input that takes place automatically according to the number of adults and children is not realized with this code.

Comment: @john, I updated my answer. You has a "typo", is [formGroupName]="i", if use `formGroupName` you need use **"i"**, if you want to use the variable **"adult"**, must be `formGroup`

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I couldn't write input in the old version of the code. When I edited earlier, I got the same error and edited the code as you like and got the same error. Cannot find control via 'AdultArray'

Comment: take account Angular is case-sensitive, it's not the same AdultArray than adultArray. And yes, Angular allow us use [formGroupName]="i" or [formGroup]="adult", (I suppose for backward compatibility, for me is more logic use [formGroup]), take account also the *ngIf initial

Comment: I wrote case sensitive, but it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error, `Error: Cannot find control with path: '# -> '`, being # a number in the FormArray iterated, due to having inside that element of the FormArray a  nested `[formGroupName]` in the template. It was fixed just by removing the square brackets, e.g.: `formGroupName="mySubFormGroupName"`.